# Selectively replace "-" by "." using gsub()

Tags: r, gsub

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c('a-b','c-d','e-f'),y=c('[1-2]','(3-4)','[5-6)'),stringsAsFactors=F)
> df
    x     y
1 a-b [1-2]
2 c-d (3-4)
3 e-f [5-6)
```

I am trying to use`gsub()`to scan all columns of`df`but replace`"-"`by`"."`only from the column(s) with alphabets, to make it look like this:

```
> df
    x     y
1 a.b [1-2]
2 c.d (3-4)
3 e.f [5-6)
```

Using`sapply(names(df), function(x) gsub("\\-", ".", df[, x]))`doesn't work:

```
> sapply(names(df), function(x) gsub("\\-", ".", df[, x]))
     x     y      
[1,] "a.b" "[1.2]"
[2,] "c.d" "(3.4)"
[3,] "e.f" "[5.6)"
```

Is there a better way to do this, either using`gsub()`or something like`make.names()`that can select columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can change the `pattern` to replace the `-` between the alphabets

```
df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = '([[:alpha:]]+)-([[:alpha:]]+)',  replacement ="\\1.\\2")
df
#    x     y
#1 a.b [1-2]
#2 c.d (3-4)
#3 e.f [5-6)
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks! I am trying to understand it: so`([[:alpha:]]+)`is for any case-independent alphabetical string and`\\1, \\2`are for "same 1st and same 2nd" ?

Comment: @Manojit Yes, it will cover A-Za-z.  As we capture those as a group (`(...)`),, in the replacement, we have the backreference (`\\1`, `\\2`) of the groups

Comment: @Manojit Or a second option without capturing would be using regex lookarounds `df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = '(?<=[[:alpha:]])-(?=[[:alpha:]])',  replacement =".", perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks again! It looks like I can use your method to replace multiple characters, like`gsub("[[:alpha:]]+)[-|/]([[:alpha:]]+)", "\\1.\\2", df)`to replace both`"-"`and`"/"`with`"."`

Comment: @Manojit Note that `[-|/]` will match any of the three chars: `-`, `|` or `/`

Comment: Oh - so`|`is not OR - thanks! So I should just use`[-/]`to mean`-`or`/`